# Custom context menu on custom TreeItems

Tags: treeview, contextmenu, javafx-8

My domain model consists of multiple types of objects that need to be listed in a tree view, let's call them A and B. Each of these types needs to do a different action when selected in the tree view.
What I have done is this:

Created an interface for both of them to implement:

```
public interface ITVItem
{
    public String toString();
    public void HandleClick();
}

public class A implements ITVItem
{
    @Override
    public void HandleClick()
    {
        //Do something      
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Item type A";
    }
}

public class B implements ITVItem
    {
        @Override
        public void HandleClick()
        {
            //Do something different
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "Item type B";
        }
    }
```

The tree view is populated like this:

```
TreeItem<ITVItem> tvItem= new TreeItem<ITVItem> (new A());
rootNode.getChildren().add(target);
treeView.setRoot(rootNode);
```

Now, when the user clicks on an item i handle it like this:

```
   @FXML
    private void SelectionChanged(MouseEvent event)
    {
        Node node = event.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode();
        // Accept clicks only on node cells, and not on empty spaces of the TreeView
        if (node instanceof Text || (node instanceof TreeCell && ((TreeCell) node).getText() != null))
        {
            tVMain.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            ITVItem tvItem = ((ITVItem) ((TreeItem) tVMain.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()).getValue());
            tvItem.HandleClick();
        }

    }
```

What I need next is to have a custom context menu for each of the domain object types (A and B) to appear when the user right-clicks. How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: Unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: you need a custom cellFactory that installs the context menu depending on the type of item

Comment: @kleopatra Agreed. please do keep in mind that code posted here is abbreviated and names are changed for simplicity and brevity. With that in mind, I am new to Java and come from a c and c# background. Could you please post an example for a cell factory with custom domain types in tree items. Or at least post a link with such example

Comment: @kleopatra Honestly, that is not very helpful, since no tutorials that I found cover this scenario with **custom domain objects** in treeItems. All of them are for TreeItem<String>, and I am pretty new to Java and JavaFX. Could you please post a link to a tutorial with **custom domain objects**

Comment: you are rigght, my comment was inappropriate, deleted. But I honestly don't see the problem: cell.getItem will return the ... well  .. item, irrespective of its type.